# sqlite multi table selection with jquery

Tags: jquery, android, sqlite

I am trying to create an android app and I have to do the follwoing:

I have two tables bill with barcode and amount columns and table billpayments with barcode and payamount columns.

How can I select from table billpayments amount where barcore = table bill barcode???

This is my code

```
function getItem1(flatname) {
var total = 0;
var payment = 0;
var previous = 0;
$.mobile.notesdb.transaction(function(t) {
    t.executeSql('SELECT barcode, buildingcode, buildingaddress, flatname, flatdescription, entryseason, period, amount FROM bill WHERE flatname = ?',
    [flatname],
    function(t, result) {
        var i,
            len = result.rows.length,
            row,
            rowb;


        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            row = result.rows.item(i);
            var html = '<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label></br>';
            $('#Code').append($(html));

            total = total + row.amount;


        function previousPayments() {
            $.mobile.notesdb.transaction(function(t) {
                t.executeSql('SELECT barcode, amount FROM billpayments WHERE barcode=?',[row.barcode],
                    function(t, resultpayment) {
                        var ii,
                            lenb = resultpayment.rows.length,
                            rowb;
                        for (ii = 0; ii < lenb; ii += 1) {
                            var rowb = resultpayment.rows.item(ii);
                            $('#displayflat article').append($('<p>' + rowb.barcode + '</p>'));
                            previous = previous + rowb.amount;
                        }
                    });
            });
        }

        previousPayments();
        $('#displayflat article').append($('<p>' + row.barcode + '</p>'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables on the barcode column. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp this should explain joins. I think you want an inner join (or just join, same thing).

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1         /* billpayments */
INNER JOIN table_name2   /* bills */
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```

Check out the site to make sure you get exactly what you want.